# Apache Shiro for desktop application?

Tags: java, apache, desktop-application, shiro, rbac

is it possibile to use Apache Shiro for desktop applications?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as they note on their [website](http://shiro.apache.org/10-minute-tutorial.html):

> Shiro can be run in any environment, from the simplest command line application to the biggest enterprise web and clustered applications,